# Unable to COPY config file in nginix /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

Tags: javascript, reactjs, docker, nginx, config

Unable to Copy config file in my project dir to /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

source file location: 
/app/nginix.conf

`COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf`

destination : /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

Steps in docker file :

```
Tried the multi stage build:

- FROM node:8.9.0 as buid
- WORKDIR /app
- COPY package.json package-lock.json ./
- RUN npm install
- COPY . ./
- RUN npm run build


- FROM nginx:alpine
- RUN mkdir -p /var/www/html/client
- COPY --from=buid /app/nginix.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
- COPY --from=buid /app/build/ /var/www/html/client
```

Tried commenting the first copy command, and it was able to copy the build and it was good.
when it is able to find the build in the app dir why is it not able to find the nginix.conf file which is also in the same dir, did a ls -la and saw the nginix.conf file.

TIA

Comment: On your local system, is `nginx.conf` in the same directory as your `Dockerfile`?

Comment: yes, Docker file and nginix.conf both are in the same directory.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the source file path is `/app/nginix.conf` then dockefile should contain:

```
COPY /app/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

If you're running `docker build` command from `/app` directory on your host then your above dockerfile should work.

**Update:**

If you're expecting /app/nginx.conf file of `node` docker image to present in `nginx:alpine` image then you need to use [multi-stage](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/) docker builds.

Change your `dockerfile` to

```
FROM node as build
WORKDIR /app
COPY package json files 
RUN npm build

FROM nginx:alpine 
COPY --from=build /app/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

This will copy `/app/nginx.conf` file from `node` image to `nginx:alpine` image.

Comment: I tried the same :
COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder-number/app/nginx.conf: no such file or directory.
After reaching this point:
FROM nginix:alpine 
the dir is changing am not able to figure that out.

Comment: Can you explain more, what output you got.

Comment: - FROM node
- WORKDIR /app
- COPY package json files 
- RUN npn build
I tried pwd and ls -la, I could see all my project files and my config file as well
FROM nginix:alpine
not sure whats going on after this point.

Comment: Does that nginx.conf file gets created in FROM node image in /app folder which you want that in FROM nginx:alpine image.

Comment: I want that from /app folder, but when am doing FROM nginx:alpine, the root is getting changed and not able to find the nginix.conf file.

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: let me know if it helped or I mis-interpretted what you are asking for.

Comment: Tried the multi stage build:

- FROM node:8.9.0 as buid
- WORKDIR /app
- COPY package.json package-lock.json ./
- RUN npm install
- COPY . ./
- RUN npm run build


- FROM nginx:alpine
- RUN mkdir -p /var/www/html/client
- COPY --from=buid /app/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
- COPY --from=buid /app/build/ /var/www/html/client

Comment: Modified the question please have a look

Answer (score 1):

If somebody is still struggling with this....

changing the WORKDIR from app to builddir worked!

```
FROM node:alpine as builder 
WORKDIR '/builddir'
COPY package.json .
RUN npm install
COPY . .
RUN npm run build

FROM nginx:alpine
COPY --from=builder /builddir/build /usr/share/nginx/html
RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```